# emotion analysis using deap preprocessed file

Tags: python, analysis

When I am trying unpickle preprocessed deap data file, the following error occurs:

```
File "D:/EEG_emotion_clasification-bd30dab4660735e8bb9c566f97b98b22ec8073f2/fitur_extraction/fft.py", line 210, in <module>
    dataset=pickle.load(open('D:\deap\data_preprocessed_python\s0'+str(i)+'.dat','rb'))

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Why use pickle to open a dat file? just open(filepath)

Comment: Because its a preprocessed pickled file

Comment: This has been mentioned in the official website:

Comment: These files contain a downsampled (to 128Hz), preprocessed and segmented version of the data in Matlab (data_preprocessed_matlab.zip) and pickled python/numpy (data_preprocessed_python.zip) formats. This version of the data is well-suited to those wishing to quickly test a classification or regression technique without the hassle of processing all the data first. Each zip file contains 32 .dat (python) or .mat (matlab) files, one per participant. Some sample code to load a python datafile is below:

import cPickle
x = cPickle.load(open('s01.dat', 'rb'))

Comment: Reading similar posts i've discovery that can be same problem of compatibility between file pickled with python 2.7 and python 3.6. What version are you using?

Comment: python 3.6, so i have used pickle instead of cpickle

Answer (score 0):

you can do this instead:

```
with open(dat_file, 'rb') as f:
    x = cPickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
```